# Code Blocks libsigc++ error

Tags: c++, user-interface, codeblocks, gtkmm

I try to use gtkmm with code blocks. I installed everything but it shows me error in libsigc++ header `signal.h`

```
fatal error: list: No such file or directory
```

I couldn't find what is wrong...

The error is in this line.

```
#include <list>
```

I added `#include <list.h>` 
and now it shows me error in `list.h` file in line namespace Gdk and error message is

```
_C:\gtkmm\include\gdkmm-2.4\gdkmm\list.h|4|error: unknown type name 'namespace'| 
C:\gtkmm\include\gdkmm-2.4\gdkmm\list.h|4|error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or 'attribute' before '{' token| 
C:\gtkmm\include\sigc++-2.0\sigc++\signal.h|8|
fatal error: list: No such file or directory| ||=== Build finished: 3 errors, 0 warnings (0 minutes, 1 seconds)
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Do you have `list` header? Can you write a simple test program that uses a `std::list`? If not, you are missing the standard C++ library, or your setup is not configured to find its headers.

Comment: I added                 

#include <list.h> 

and now it shows me error in list.h file in line 


_namespace Gdk {_


error message is

_C:\gtkmm\include\gdkmm-2.4\gdkmm\list.h|4|error: unknown type name 'namespace'|
C:\gtkmm\include\gdkmm-2.4\gdkmm\list.h|4|error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '{' token|
C:\gtkmm\include\sigc++-2.0\sigc++\signal.h|8|fatal error: list: No such file or directory|
||=== Build finished: 3 errors, 0 warnings (0 minutes, 1 seconds) ===|
_

Comment: Show the command that you're trying to compile with.

Comment: It is not `#include <list.h>`, it is  `#include <list>`.

Comment: I am also gettin the same error on ubuntu. Can any one tell how to check if stl is present in ubuntu or not??